# How to disassemble fasm-generated binary?

Tags: assembly, disassembly, fasm

I am writing program in FASM assembler, and want to see what code is generated after all macro expansions. One usually can disasseble binary with `objdump -d`, but for binary, generated by fasm, it outputs only following:

```
$ cat true.fasm
format ELF64 executable
sys_exit = 60
entry $
      mov eax, sys_exit
      xor edi, edi
      syscall
$ fasm true.fasm
$ objdum -d ./true
out/true:     file format elf64-x86-64
```

What I can do is to load binary into `gdb`, start it with `starti` and decode instructions with `x/10i $rip`, which is sub-optimal. Is there non-interactive command that can do the same?

Comment: FASM doesn't create ELF section info (so there is no `.text` section), only program headers that tell the OS how to map it into memory.  I don't know a good convenient way to disassemble it, other than treating it like a flat binary and disassembling everything (e.g. `ndisasm -b32`).  Then finding the start of the actual instructions yourself.

Comment: You can try using the `-D` (capital D, disassemble all) option of objdump to see if that works better.

Comment: `-D` results in same output: ` file format elf64-x86-64`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easly using [radare2](https://radare.org), using `pdf` command that means `disassemble` :

```
% cat test.asm 
format ELF64 executable
sys_exit = 60
entry $
  mov rax, sys_exit
  xor rdi, rdi
  syscall
% ./fasm test.asm
flat assembler  version 1.73.04  (16384 kilobytes memory) 1 passes, 132 bytes.
% file test
test: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
% r2 -AA test
[x] Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
[x] Analyze function calls (aac)
[x] Analyze len bytes of instructions for references (aar)
[x] Check for objc references
[x] Check for vtables
[x] Type matching analysis for all functions (aaft)
[x] Propagate noreturn information
[x] Use -AA or aaaa to perform additional experimental analysis.
[x] Finding function preludes
[x] Enable constraint types analysis for variables
-- In visual mode press 'c' to toggle the cursor mode. Use tab to navigate
[0x00400078]> pdf
        ;-- segment.LOAD0:
        ;-- rip:
┌ 12: entry0 ();
│           0x00400078      48c7c03c0000.  mov rax, 0x3c               ; '<' ; 60 ; [00] -rwx segment size 12 named LOAD0
│           0x0040007f      4831ff         xor rdi, rdi
└           0x00400082      0f05           syscall
[0x00400078]>
```